# Javascript : Replace Backslash and double Quotes with some other char

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace \" with null or some other character,and trying to JSON parse but its not happening at al. Below is my code.

```
var s = '{"total":2,"data":[{"assignExist":"Online","status":"Started Work","state":"Ready for Download","assignInfoletId":"100003","loadAssignId":"false","assignAdditionalInfo":[{}],"assignName":"BC Simple Form","assignId":"100003","assignProcessId":"3"},{"assignExist":"Online","status":"Started Work","state":"Ready for Download","assignInfoletId":"100003","loadAssignId":"false","assignAdditionalInfo":[{"Name":"Rishant","City":"Bangalore","Desc":"Platform-Dev","AUDIT_COMPANIES":"[{\"AUDIT_COMPANY\":\"Golder\",\"AUDITORS\":[{\"TPA_AUDITOR\":\"Swadhin Ray\",\"IS_LEAD\":\"0\",\"ASSIGNMENTS\":\"Assigmens, Sdsfds,sdfdsfd\"},{\"TPA_AUDITOR\":\"Praveen Kayetha\",\"IS_LEAD\":\"1\",\"ASSIGNMENTS\":\"Assigmens, Sdsfds,sdfdsfd\"}]}]"}],"assignName":"BC Simple Form","assignId":"100001","assignProcessId":"2"}]}';


s= s.replace(/\\"/g, "DOUBLEQ");

console.log(s);
var data = JSON.parse(s);
console.log(data);
```

solution to this i found is

```
var dataResponse = JSON.parse(s);

      var dataLen = dataResponse.data.length;

      for(var i=0;i<dataLen;i++){
        var audit_co = dataResponse.data[i].assignAdditionalInfo[0].AUDIT_COMPANIES;
        if(typeof audit_co!= 'undefined')
          dataResponse.data[i].assignAdditionalInfo[0].AUDIT_COMPANIES = JSON.parse(audit_co.replace(/\\"/g,'"'));
      }
```

Comment: Why do you have illegal JSON? The easy solution would surely be simply to generate valid JSON.

Comment: @lonesomeday The JSON string in the OP's sample is valid.

Comment: @Tomalak Odd, it causes an error for me. The point remains, however, that the solution to invalid JSON would not be to fix it with Javascript but to generate valid JSON in the first place.

Comment: @lonesomeday The OP's string is broken when interpreted as a JS string, but it is valid when interpreted as a stream of characters. jsonlint is doing the latter, JavaScript the former, naturally. Both ways are correct in their respective contexts.

Comment: @lonesomeday I suspect the OP just copy-pasted a working, valid JSON string into the source code as a literal, thus losing one level of backslash-escaping. That's the only explanation.

Comment: Actually, speaking act JSON Structure, its given by one of the team in our firm, they said they are using some java api to construct it. and about removing backslash i just wrote few lines of code which made it work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's illegal JSON - it looks like JSON inside JSON, which is valid. Try just parsing it without changing it.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to parse it to invalid JSON:
You can access values directly:

```
<script>
    var s = {"total":2,"data":[{"assignExist":"Online","status":"Started Work","state":"Ready for Download","assignInfoletId":"100003","loadAssignId":"false","assignAdditionalInfo":[{}],"assignName":"BC Simple Form","assignId":"100003","assignProcessId":"3"},{"assignExist":"Online","status":"Started Work","state":"Ready for Download","assignInfoletId":"100003","loadAssignId":"false","assignAdditionalInfo":[{"Name":"Rishant","City":"Bangalore","Desc":"Platform-Dev","AUDIT_COMPANIES":"[{\"AUDIT_COMPANY\":\"Golder\",\"AUDITORS\":[{\"TPA_AUDITOR\":\"Swadhin Ray\",\"IS_LEAD\":\"0\",\"ASSIGNMENTS\":\"Assigmens, Sdsfds,sdfdsfd\"},{\"TPA_AUDITOR\":\"Praveen Kayetha\",\"IS_LEAD\":\"1\",\"ASSIGNMENTS\":\"Assigmens, Sdsfds,sdfdsfd\"}]}]"}],"assignName":"BC Simple Form","assignId":"100001","assignProcessId":"2"}]};
    console.log(s.data);
</script>
```

Comment: `s` is an object in your code, not a string. This answer does not have anything to do with JSON.

Comment: @ Tomalak What is JSON can you please explain?

Comment: JSON is a string format. It has nothing to do with JavaScript objects, which you are using in your code. Add single quotes around your `s`, just like the OP has them, and then try your answer again. You will find that it no longer works.

Comment: I know it will not work...And I also know Javascript Object Notation...I just gave OP suggession not to deal with string...He can directly access it with above method. It will only work when you Parse the string to JSON..

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have this:

```
var s = '{"plainValue": 42, "nestedJSON": "{\"nested\": \"json\"}"}';
```

This is not valid because it translates to the following in-memory string:

```
{"plainValue": 42, "nestedJSON": "{"nested": "json"}"}
                                   ^      ^  ^    ^     invalid double quotes
```

The solution is simple: Don't use nested JSON. There is *no reason whatsoever* to nest a JSON string into a JSON string. Here is what you should have.

```
var s = '{"plainValue": 42, "nestedObject": {"nested": "object"}}';
```

Syntactically valid but foolish would be

```
var s = '{"plainValue": 42, "nestedJSON": "{\\"nested\\": \\"json\\"}"}';
```

Fix the problem at the source. The function that generates your JSON string is broken.

Answer (score 0):

when you create the 's' string, the \" is already esaped, so the \ char is dissapear. Thats why you cant replace \" with something, because its doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The following method should work:

```
var s = JSON.stringify({"total":2,"data":[{"assignExist":"Online","status":"Started Work","state":"Ready for Download","assignInfoletId":"100003","loadAssignId":"false","assignAdditionalInfo":[{}],"assignName":"BC Simple Form","assignId":"100003","assignProcessId":"3"},{"assignExist":"Online","status":"Started Work","state":"Ready for Download","assignInfoletId":"100003","loadAssignId":"false","assignAdditionalInfo":[{"Name":"Rishant","City":"Bangalore","Desc":"Platform-Dev","AUDIT_COMPANIES":"[{\"AUDIT_COMPANY\":\"Golder\",\"AUDITORS\":[{\"TPA_AUDITOR\":\"Swadhin Ray\",\"IS_LEAD\":\"0\",\"ASSIGNMENTS\":\"Assigmens, Sdsfds,sdfdsfd\"},{\"TPA_AUDITOR\":\"Praveen Kayetha\",\"IS_LEAD\":\"1\",\"ASSIGNMENTS\":\"Assigmens, Sdsfds,sdfdsfd\"}]}]"}],"assignName":"BC Simple Form","assignId":"100001","assignProcessId":"2"}]});

var data = JSON.parse(s);
```